# Minimum account balance Changed?

Tags: horizon, stellar-sdk, base-reserve

The base_reserve_in_stroops says 5,000,000 (0.05 XLM) in the following URL. This is a recent ledger entry. Does this mean it only takes 0.1 XLM (2 * 0.5 XLM) to create an account now?

https://horizon.stellar.org/ledgers/20382718

Comment: The `base_reserve` wasn't changed. It is still 0.5 XLM.

Comment: Then what is the value in the "base_reserve_in_stroops" field. It used to show 100,000,000. https://horizon.stellar.org/ledgers/10382718

Comment: And btw 2*0.5 = 1 not 0.1

Comment: 100,000,000 stroops = 10 XLM. A year ago `base_reserve` was 10 XLM.

Comment: Ok. I see where the confusion is now. I thought 1 XLM = 100,000,000 (100 million stroops) instead of 10,000,000 stroops. Clarity achieved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As stated here https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/ledger.html that's:

> The reserve the network uses when calculating an account’s minimum balance.

It's not the account’s minimum balance itself.

Comment: Yes and the formula is (2 + # of entries) * base reserve. For a new account that's (2 + 0) * 0.05 = 0.1 XLM.